# mongoose $aggregation $match $or between dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, or-operator

I want to filter like this in an aggegration. Here is an example of mongoose query. The same thing i want to do in an aggegration. What i want to do is get all measurements between 2016-06-01T22:52:46Z and 2016-06-02T22:52:46Z and the other values

```
Measurement
  .find({})
  .or([{
    'date': {
      '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-01T22:52:46Z'),
      '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-02T22:52:46Z')
    }
  }, {
    'date': {
      '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-10T22:52:46Z'),
      '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-11T22:52:46Z')
    }
  }, {
    'date': {
      '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-14T22:52:46Z'),
      '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-15T22:52:46Z')
    }
  }, {
    'date': {
      '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-26T22:52:46Z'),
      '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-27T22:52:46Z')
    }
  }])
  .exec();
```

This is what i tried but it didn't do the same job. And the IDE says dublicated keys 'date'

```
db.measurements.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    $or: [{
      date: {
        '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-01T22:52:46Z'),
        '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-02T22:52:46Z')
      },
      date: {
        '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-10T22:52:46Z'),
        '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-11T22:52:46Z')
      },
      date: {
        '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-14T22:52:46Z'),
        '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-15T22:52:46Z')
      },
      date: {
        '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-26T22:52:46Z'),
        '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-27T22:52:46Z')
      }
    }]
  }
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have some example of data?
Try this code:

```
db.measurements.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    $or: [
    { date: {
        '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-01T22:52:46Z'),
        '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-02T22:52:46Z')
      }},
      { date: {
        '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-10T22:52:46Z'),
        '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-11T22:52:46Z')
      }},
      { date: {
        '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-14T22:52:46Z'),
        '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-15T22:52:46Z')
      }},
      { date: {
        '$gte': ISODate('2016-06-26T22:52:46Z'),
        '$lte': ISODate('2016-06-27T22:52:46Z')
      }}
    ]
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much it does the job!

Comment: My commendation: Take the MongoDb cources. It is free and very helpful. https://university.mongodb.com/